# How to compare LocalDateTime values in JPQL query?

Tags: java, hql, jpql, localdatetime

It is necessary to select dataset using JPQL query with optional condition - comparing the field value (`LocalDateTime` type) with a user-specified parameter (also LocalDateTime type).

First I made a well working code:

```
return entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT new com.******.*******.*******.****.models.dto.SomeDto " +
    "(s.id, " +
    "s.userId) " +
    "s.persistDate) " +
    "FROM Some s WHERE s.userId = :userId 
    AND s.persistDate >= :userDateTime", SomeDTO.class)
    .setParameter("userId", userId)
    .setParameter("userDateTime", userDateTime)
```

This code works but there is one problem:
this condition may exist or may not exist - dependent on app logic. Therefore, there is a need not to use injection using .setParameter (for this condition), but to form a string (which may be empty) depending on the logic and then add to the request:

```
String extraCondition = (userDateString.equals("false")) ? "" : 
    "AND s.persistDateTime >= " + userDateString;
```

```
return entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT new com.******.*******.*******.****.models.dto.SomeDto " +
    "(s.id, " +
    "s.userId) " +
    "s.persistDate) " +
    "FROM Some s WHERE s.userId = :userId " + extraCondition, SomeDTO.class)
    .setParameter("userId", userId)
```

But the problem is that no matter how I tried to format the userDateString variable, I get an Internal Server Error.I even tried using just a text string instead of variable (tried with different formatting):

```
String extraCondition = (userDateString.equals("false")) ? "" : 
    "AND s.persistDateTime >= 2023-01-27T23:30:50";
```

But the result is also bad - Internal Server Error.

I also tried using the .isAfter method instead of the ">=" operator, but that didn't help either.

How to inject `LocalDateTime` values comparing into query as String?

Comment: By the way, if your `persistDate` means you are recording the moment when an object/row was saved to the database, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong Java class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even if the date string may or may not be necesssary, you can (and should!) still use parameter injection, not formatted values.

Basically, your code should look like this:

```
String queryStr = ....;
boolean someCondition = <expensive_test_here>;
if(someCondition) {
  queryStr += " AND s.persistDate >= :userDateTime";
}
Query q = em.createQuery(queryStr).setParameter("userId", userId);
if(someCondition) {
  q.setParameter("userDateTime", userDateTime);
}
```

Comment: This is a working solution, but one thing confuses me: is it normal that the same condition checked  twice?
If the date casting to a string (as I initially wanted), then it need to check the condition only once.

Comment: @ingors yes, you need to check twice.  you can cache the condition evaluation in a local variable if you are concerned about that, then re-use the result.  i updated the answer with an example of that.

Comment: Wonderful! Now I like this code. Thank you very much (unfortunately my rating is not enough to make +1)

Comment: @ingors as the original question asker, i think you should be able to accept this as the correct answer.